# R - Speeding up loop over array dimensions

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am working with an array with dimensions

```
[1] 290 259  55   4
```

For each repetition of the last three dimensions, I want to perform a rolling mean on the 290 elements of the first dimension, reducing the number of elements to 289. Finally, I need to create a data frame with the updated values.

The following code achieves what I need, but it takes a LONG time to run (actually, I have to interrupt it before the end).

```
library(zoo)

# Generate random data with same dimensions as mine
my.array <- array(1:16524200, dim=c(290,259,55,4))

# Get dimension sizes
dim2 <- dim(my.array)[2]
dim3 <- dim(my.array)[3]
dim4 <- dim(my.array)[4]

# Pre-allocate data frame to be used within the loop
df2 <- data.frame()

# Loop over dimensions
for (i in 1:dim4) {
  for (j in 1:dim3) {
    for (k in 1:dim2) {

      # Take rolling average
      u <- rollapply(my.array[,k,j,i], 2, mean)

      # Assemble data frame
      df1 <- data.frame(time=i, level=j, lat=k, wind=u)
      df2 <- rbind(df2, df1)

    }
  }
}
# Very slow, and uses only one machine core
```

I feel like it is possible to improve the processing time of this code by using vectorization or even some kind of parallelism, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions to make this code more efficient?

Comment: Never build data.frames iteratively. Each time you call `rbind`, it is copying *the entire frame* into a new object and over-writing `df2`. It might work for a few dozen, but (as you can see) this scales *horribly*.

Comment: @r2evans that makes sense, but... What would be an alternative?

Comment: In general, `something <- lapply(list_of_stuff, somefunc)` and then `do.call(rbind, something)` (though this question requires a little more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option to [flatten the multidimensional array first](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-quot-flatten-quot-a-multidimensional-array-into-a-dataframe-td4572108.html#a4572132) before using `data.table` to calculate the rolling mean

```
library(data.table)
system.time({
    ans <- setDT(as.data.frame.table(my.array))[
        , .(wind=((Freq + shift(Freq)) / 2)[-1L]), 
        .(time=Var4, level=Var3, lat=Var2)]
    cols <- c("time", "level", "lat")
    ans[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) match(x, unique(x))), .SDcols=cols]
})
ans
```

output:

```
          time level lat       wind
       1:    1     1   1        1.5
       2:    1     1   1        2.5
       3:    1     1   1        3.5
       4:    1     1   1        4.5
       5:    1     1   1        5.5
      ---                          
16467216:    4    55 259 16524195.5
16467217:    4    55 259 16524196.5
16467218:    4    55 259 16524197.5
16467219:    4    55 259 16524198.5
16467220:    4    55 259 16524199.5
```

timings:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   4.90    1.16    5.66
```

and for comparison:

```
library(zoo)
system.time({
    as.data.frame.table(apply(my.array, c(2,3,4), rollmean, 2))  
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  21.89    0.63   22.51
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten how fast `data.table` can be! I am marking this as the official answer, since my data can be up to 10x bigger than the example I gave, and using this answer would save me a lot of time.

Comment: I am struggling with converting the resulting data table to an array with the dimensions `289 259  55   4` (similar to the original one). Do you happen to have any hints on this?

Comment: I am guessing it’s using array? Maybe post another question? I am not with a PC right now

Answer (score 6):

`apply()` works on any number of dimensions so you can achieve the same result much more quickly using the following wrapped in `as.data.frame.table()` to efficiently convert the output from an array to a data frame:

```
library(zoo)
df <- as.data.frame.table(apply(my.array, c(2,3,4), rollmean, 2))
```

Not strictly necessary but this can be tidied up to match your original output:

```
idx <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[idx] <- sapply(df[idx], as.integer)

df <- setNames(df[c(4,3,2,5)], c("time", "level", "lat", "wind"))
```

Check if the result is the same:

```
identical(df2, df)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I had forgotten about `as.data.frame.table`, that does an incredible job of speeding things up (over 2x on initial testing).

Answer (score 5):

Up front, you are suffering from the 2nd circle of R's Inferno (https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf): growing objects. Each time you call `rbind`, it makes a complete copy of the frame, does the r-binding, then overwrites that complete copy over the original variable name. So while it might work without noticeable slow-down for the first few dozen, it will slow down a bit over 100 or so ... and you're doing it 56,980 times.

It is generally much better to process things into a `list` and then do the `rbind` once at the end on the entire list, as in `do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)`. Granted, you still may have the computational challenge of doing something potentially hard ... luckily `zoo` is about as efficient as you can get for window operations, and this one is not impossibly hard.

I'll demonstrate on a significantly-reduced problem set (since I don't think it matters if we're looking at 16M or 1.5M iterations.

```r
my.array <- array(1:1502200, dim=c(290,259,5,4))
eg <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(dim(my.array)[-1], seq_len))
dim(eg)
# [1] 5180    3
head(eg)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    1    1    1
# 2    2    1    1
# 3    3    1    1
# 4    4    1    1
# 5    5    1    1
# 6    6    1    1

system.time({
  list_of_frames <- Map(function(i,j,k) {
    u <- zoo::rollapply(my.array[,i,j,k], 2, mean)
    data.frame(i, j, k, wind = u)
  }, eg[[1]], eg[[2]], eg[[3]])
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    5.79    0.00    5.80 
head(list_of_frames[[5]])
#   i j k   wind
# 1 5 1 1 1161.5
# 2 5 1 1 1162.5
# 3 5 1 1 1163.5
# 4 5 1 1 1164.5
# 5 5 1 1 1165.5
# 6 5 1 1 1166.5

system.time({
  out <- do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.50    0.03    0.53 
nrow(out)
# [1] 1497020
rbind(head(out), tail(out))
#           i j k      wind
# 1         1 1 1       1.5
# 2         1 1 1       2.5
# 3         1 1 1       3.5
# 4         1 1 1       4.5
# 5         1 1 1       5.5
# 6         1 1 1       6.5
# 1497015 259 5 4 1502194.5
# 1497016 259 5 4 1502195.5
# 1497017 259 5 4 1502196.5
# 1497018 259 5 4 1502197.5
# 1497019 259 5 4 1502198.5
# 1497020 259 5 4 1502199.5
```

Explanation:

- `do.call(expand.grid, ...)` is creating a frame of all the `i,j,k` combinations you need, dynamically on the dimensions of your array.
- `Map(f, is, js, ks)` runs the function `f` with the 1st argument of each of `is`, `js`, and `ks` (notional for this bullet), so Map looks something like:

  ```r
  f(is[1], js[1], ks[1])
  f(is[2], js[2], ks[2])
  f(is[3], js[3], ks[3])
  # ...
  ```
- then we combine them in one call using `do.call(rbind, ...)`. We really have to use `do.call` here because this call is analogous to

  ```r
  rbind(list_of_frames[[1]], list_of_frames[[2]], ..., list_of_frames[[5180]])
  ```

  (over to you if you'd prefer to write out this version).